# How does reselect affect rendering of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, reselect

I don't really understand how does reselect reduces component's rendering. This is what I have without reselect:

```
const getListOfSomething = (state) => (
  state.first.list[state.second.activeRecord]
);

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  console.log(state.first.list, state.second.activeRecord);
  return {
    ...ownProps,
    listOfSomething: getListOfSomething(state)
  }
};
```

It compounds an element from some list based on some value. Render is called each time anything in the state changes, so for example my `console.log` outputs:

```
{}, ""
{}, ""
{}, ""
{}, "1"
{"filled", "1"}
```

because something is going on in the different part of store. Thus the component is rendered 5 times, 2 redundantly.

Using reselect however:

```
const getList = state => state.first.list;
const getActiveRecord = state => state.second.activeRecord;
const listOfSomething = (list, activeRecord) => {
  console.log(list, activeRecord);
  return list[activeRecord];
}
const getListOfSomething = createSelector(getList, getActiveRecord, listOfSomething);

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  console.log(state.first.list, state.second.activeRecord);
  return {
    ...ownProps,
    listOfSomething: getListOfSomething(state)
  }
};
```

Here my first selector `console.log` outputs:

```
{}, ""
{}, "1"
{"filled", "1"}
```

The second:

```
{}, ""
{}, ""
{}, ""
{}, "1"
{"filled", "1"}
```

And the component is rendered properly - 3 times !

Why is that so? Why is the component rendered only 3 times? What's exectly going on here?

Answer (score 5):

React-Redux's `connect` function relies on shallow-equality comparisons.  Each time the store updates and a component's `mapState` function runs, that connected component checks to see if the *contents* of the returned object changed.  If `mapState` returned something different, then the wrapped component must need to re-render.

Reselect uses "memoization", which means it saves a copy of the last inputs and outputs, and if it sees the same inputs twice in a row, it returns the last output rather than recalculating things.  So, a Reselect-based selector function will return the same object references if the inputs didn't change, which means that it's more likely that `connect` will see that nothing is different and the wrapped component won't re-render.

See the new [Redux FAQ section on Immutable Data](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ImmutableData.html) for more info on how immutability and comparisons work with Redux and React-Redux.